# Cloned my laptop’s HDD to a new SSD. Now it won’t work unless my old HDD is connected externally

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

Using Macrium Reflect, I cloned my 2TB HDD to a new 500GB SSD. After installing the new drive, I got hit with “no bootable devices found”.

I ran Macrium’s rescue media to try and resolve boot problems, but it didn’t fix anything. I could only get my laptop to boot again with the new SSD when I plugged in my old HDD thru USB and used it as an entry point to the Windows Recovery Environment. From there I used this answer to fix the issue: https://superuser.com/a/1375491

I know now with 100% certainty that my laptop’s using its new SSD when it’s booted up. But here’s the issue: the moment I unplug the old HDD, my laptop immediately bluescreens with error INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE, and won’t boot again until I plug it back in.

I feel like there’s something easy that I’m missing here.

Comment: Have you cloned the whole disk including the EFI partition?

Comment: The total amount of data on my HDD was smaller than the SSD capacity, so yes I copied over every partition.

Comment: If so it should work. Make sure, in UEFI settings, that the new drive is first priority for booting. Then the firmware should read correctly the EFI entries (in another boot setting). Right now it seems to be getting the information from the external drive.